# how to create decoration like comment reply section of facebook android app in android native

Tags: android

[that picture of decoration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G18bu.jpg)

i try to custom that using Recyclerview ItemDecoration but doesn't look like the result I wanted in the photo, so how to custom ItemDecoration of Recyclerview make the same result of facebook comment reply section in this picture

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.